# Why do backgrounded commands in Zsh functions not show correctly in jobs?

Tags: zsh, background-process, function, job-control, jobs

In Bash 5.2, the output of `jobs` after either of the following is identical modulo job numbers:

```
sleep 3
# press C-z
```

```
s() { sleep 3; }
s
# press C-z
```

In both, `jobs` produces something like

```
[1]+  Stopped                sleep 3
```

---

In Zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0), the first produces similar enough output containing the `sleep` command:

```
[1]  + suspended  sleep 3
```

The second produces almost useless output:

```
[1]  + suspended
```

---

I have [lots of functions that invoke Vim with different arguments or completions](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/854f9498cb90af3b84cb961a9e97cf0009970f31/links/zsh/vim.zsh); suspending Vim during the execution of any of them via `C-z` or `:suspend` puts such a useless entry in `jobs`. It's not uncommon for me to have 2 or more such jobs, in which case it is rather difficult to keep them straight.

Why does Zsh do this and is there a way for me to fix it?

Comment: IIRC there's a long-standing bug where zsh “forgets” a job's description in some circumstances. I can reproduce this on Ubuntu 20.04. As a workaround, the name of the function is still present in `$jobtexts`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' interesting. Bug indeed… `$jobtexts` actually reports the function invocation, too, which I'm fine with. Maybe it's time to roll my own `jobs` (I already use `j() { jobs -l; }`)